# jquery dialog not triggering media queries on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use jquery dialog to pop open a modal with an iframe to another page of the same website. 
The problem is with media queries not triggering in IE8 and IE7 when the modal is resized.
(Note: the queries DO work on IE7 and IE8 on other places - thanks to css3-mediaqueries.js library, just not when modal is resized)

The relevant markup is as follows:

```
 <div id="lotrModal" title=""><iframe id="lotrIframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Javascript to invoke the jquery dialog

```
$("#lotrIframe").attr("src", "/leaders-on-the-road/");
$( "#lotrModal" ).dialog({ height: 615, width:800, modal: true });
```

In the CSS files, there is various media queries used to decrease # of columns depending on the screen size.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1155px) {

.record {
    width: 42%;
    margin-left: 5%;
} }
```

I dont have this problem on any other browser and I know that the media queries do work for me on IE8 and IE7 (if I manually go to leaders-on-the-road, the src page and resize the screen, then the columns ARE being changed)

Anyone have any ideas why dialog resize in IE8 and below is not triggering the media queries when it works everywhere else? I've looked around but haven't hit any relevant posts on this - any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: IE8 DOES NOT support media queries. Are you sure you're not using a javascript library which adds that support in? If so, which one? You can probably trigger it to do a recheck at the appropriate time.

Comment: Correct. I'm using css3-mediaqueries.js which works great but not when modal is resized